# Calling a C function that is referenced by a C pointer to that function with Haskell FFI

Tags: haskell, ffi

There is a functions in the 'C' wiringPi library with type,

```
extern void (*pinMode) (int pin, int mode) ;
```

I tried calling it from haskell using the FFI with FunPtr. So I did,

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "wiringPi.h &pinMode" c_pinMode 
        :: FunPtr (CInt -> CInt -> IO ())
foreign import ccall "dynamic" dc_pinMode 
        :: FunPtr (CInt -> CInt -> IO ()) -> (CInt -> CInt -> IO ())
```

but for some reason, even though it compiles, it doesn't seem to be calling the function that 'pinMode' points to.

So I tried using normal Foreign.Ptr, thinking I might be able to peek at the Ptr to get a reference to the underlying 'C' function pointed to by 'pinMode'. So I tried,

```
foreign import ccall "wiringPi.h &pinMode" c_pinMode
    :: Ptr (Ptr (CInt -> CInt -> IO ()))
```

And then, in the implementation of the haskell function that calls 'pinMode' I used peek twice to get a reference to the underlying function. But I keep getting compilation errors where the compiler tell me that the function of type `(CInt -> CInt -> IO ())` is not an instance of the 'Storable' typeclass.

So I checked out the storable typeclass, to make `(CInt -> CInt -> IO ())` an instance of the storable typeclass.. The minimum implementation required is for peek, poke and a few other functions.. I realized, it really shouldn't be so difficult to call a function that is reference by a pointer..

I feel like I am missing something fundamental. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: `extern void (*pinMode) (int pin, int mode);` declares `pinMode` as a _pointer_ to a function taking two `int`s and returning `void`. Try `foreign import ccall unsafe "wiringPi.h pinMode" c_pinMode`, taking the address of the pointer gives you one level of indirection too much (but I'm not too familiar with the FFI, so I'm not 100% sure I interpret it right).

Comment: Is `pinMode` a function or a function pointer? If it's a function pointer, I think the type of `foreign import ccall unsafe "wiringPi.h &pinMode" c_pinMode` should be `Ptr (FunPtr (CInt -> CInt -> IO ()))`.

Comment: @nymk pinMode is a pointer to a procedure that takes 2 integers as parameters. Say, I rewrite the type of the the import to what you mentioned. Is it still possible to get a reference to the underlying function on the haskell side? Because, if type of c_pinMode is `Ptr (FunPtr (CInt -> CInt -> IO ()))`, I can't do `c_pinMode (3 :: CInt) (4 :: CInt)`. I do not think this works. However I will try what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a C function pointer defined in foo.c.

```
void foo(int x, int y)
{
    printf("foo: sum = %d\n", x+y);
}

typedef void (*FooPtr) (int, int);
FooPtr fooptr = foo;
```

In order to call the function that `fooptr` points to, we need to not only declare a static address import, but also a dynamic import. The dynamic stub can help us convert `FunPtr` values to corresponding Haskell functions.

```
type Foo = CInt -> CInt -> IO ()

foreign import ccall "foo.c &fooptr" fooptr :: Ptr (FunPtr Foo)
foreign import ccall "dynamic" mkFooFun :: FunPtr Foo -> Foo

main = do
    funcptr <- peek fooptr
    mkFooFun funcptr 1 2
```

`fooptr` is an imported address that points to a foreign function. Its type is neither `Ptr (Ptr a)` nor `FunPtr a`.

If we import `foo`'s address, its type will be `FunPtr Foo`. In order to use it, we still need the help from `mkFooFun`.

```
foreign import ccall "foo.c &foo" fooptr2 :: FunPtr Foo
main = mkFooFun fooptr2 1 2
```

In this example, since we can access `foo`, the simplest way to call `foo` is

```
foreign import ccall "foo.c foo" foo :: Foo
main = foo 1 2
```

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer. I actually came back here to post the same solution after I found out how to do it myself a few minutes back. But going through your answer, I learnt it more comprehensively. Most importantly, the fact that fooptr is merely an imported memory address.